# PHP update instead of insert and return message

Tags: php, sql

I am connecting via Java to Php which connects to a database. Instead of inserting I am trying to update a row.

```
<?php 

$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "Table";
$dbuser     = "Example";
$dbpass     = "Example";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$data = array($_POST["username"], $_POST["firstName"],$_POST["lastName"]);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Table(username, firstName, lastName) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute($data); 

?>
```

I am trying to have it instead be an update function where it will update the info for the row with that username in the database. Something like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Table(username, firstName, lastName) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
```

Also is it possible to pass back a message also to Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exeute an `UPDATE` statement. This will require you to submit the database tables primary key so that you know which record to update.

Assuming `username` is your database primary key:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Table SET firstName = ?, lastName = ? WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST["firstName"],$_POST["lastName"], $_POST["username"]));
```

To send a message to your Java application, `echo` a response:

```
echo "your message";
```